# Unity - How to pass null in the constructor parameter for nullable int

Tags: unity-container

I have a class that takes nullable int as parameter.

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(int? p)
    {
        // ......
    }

    // ......
}
```

How do I resolve it using unity (passing null as parameter)?

```
myContainer.RegisterType<Test>(new InjectionConstructor(10));
```

This works passing 10 as value, but if I pass null, it throws exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edited to use generics:

Try to use InjectionParameter instead:

```
container.RegisterType<Test>(new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter<int?>(null)));
```

Comment: Except your first answer didn't work, your answer was only correct after editing, which was performed after my answer was posted.

Comment: My preedit answer work but was not using generics. Anyway I was joking because we are almost paralel in time answering the question. No offense.

Comment: That's OK, I did try your original answer however, and it didn't work for me, maybe I'll try again later :)

Comment: When I was in need of null parameters in constructor I use this solution from Unity forum that works for me. It was my first answer without generics. http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/257313 Should work for you too.

Answer (score 5):

Use an `InjectionParameter<T>` of the correct type, i.e.

```
container.RegisterType<Test>(new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter<int?>(null)));
```

This has been tested in visual studio.