# How to convert param "null" to be null

Tags: xml, unity-container

I have an XML configuration file that looks like this:

```
<register type='MyType'>
    <constructor>
        ...
        <param name='myString' value='null'/>
        ...
    </constructor>
</register>
```

How do I convert the string `"null"` into the `null` value?

I have tried specifying `value=''` but I get the error:

> The attribute value must be present and non-empty.

And tried `<param name='myString'/>` which gives the error

> The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

And finally (which is what [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_instances) seems to suggest)

```
<instance name='myStringVal' />
<register type='MyType'>
    <constructor>
        ...
        <param name='myString' dependencyName='myStringVal'/>
        ...
    </constructor>
</register>
```

Which throws an `ArgumentNullException`

**Edit:** and now I have also tried the `optional` tag

```
<register type='MyType'>
    <constructor>
        ...
        <param name='myString'>
            <optional />
        </param>
        ...
    </constructor>
</register>
```

This also throws an `ArgumentNullException`

Note: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570168/unity-how-to-pass-null-in-the-constructor-parameter-for-nullable-int) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392670/register-null-as-instance-in-unity-container) (and probably several others), but these are about configuration in C#, I want to configure in XML.

Comment: Why not `if (value.Equals("null")) { value = null; }`?

Comment: @ThePcLuddite - that seems like a real hack: I would be polluting `MyType` with special handling that is only relevant for when I am using it with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type converter to convert the string in configuration to a null string.  Unity won't let you put an empty string as the value in the configuration so, unfortunately, the type converter will have to use a "magic string" to identity the null value:

```
<register type="MyClass" >
  <constructor>
    <param name="configValue" value="null" typeConverter="NullStringConverter" />
  </constructor>
</register>
```

In the above "null" is the magic string that the type converter will look for:

```
public class NullStringConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null || 
            (value.GetType() == typeof(string) && 
            String.Compare(value.ToString(), "null", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that XML has a true NULL value.  Have you looked at using an `xsi:nil` attribute?